# Which artificial neural network concepts should I be applying?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'd like to build an ANN for controlling a device, and having trouble figuring out which concepts I should be learning and applying for this, that would make it plausible. In general, the problem can be solved simpler with a predefined algorithm, but I'd like to build ANN for this just for the sake of my exploration of the concepts.

I want to start with ANN that, given target temperature, current state of the heater, and a few dozen (or however many) points of temperature in the past, make a decision whether the heater needs to be on or off. Now, the caveat is that I'd like it be responsive to the changes in the environment, without pre-training for all possible conditions. E.g. start with some very simple (or even random) model, take a decision, feed it into a simulator, then take an output "a minute later," and use that data for the cost function. And so on. Particularly complex part of this (or am I mistaken here?) is the latency of the action. You see result only, say, 2 minutes after the heater is on, and after it's off, temperature keeps climbing for another 4-5 minutes.

There is a lot of information on classification and time series prediction (particularly with LSTM that hints it might be useful here), but I can't find any that talk about controlling a system with such a feedback loop.

I'd appreciate if you can point me to some concepts that would be relevant in solving this problem using ANN, or maybe to some discussion of similar problems and how they are being solved.

PS: just to give some context for where I'm going with this, eventually (while it might be a bit ambitious, mostly for small dataset), I'd like to expand the system to control my HVAC zones by manipulating damper angles throughout the heating cycle so that target temperature is maintained in multiple room independently. And I'd like it to learn as it goes, as outside environment changes, heating cycle turns into cooling cycle, doors are being left open, etc.

Answer (score 0):

IBM guys actually published timeseries forecasting DNN model that brings in external information to predict demands. See here http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/riemer16.pdf

Your question seems to overlap with their problem setting. They use attention quite robustly (robust in the sense of tuning) to bring together historical time series observation, various contexts, and other external variables.

Also they do a nice job in Related Work section for literature survey so that should help too.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very careful abut using ANN here. Mind that they can be relatively easily fooled and are proven to memorize (as opposed to learn) far more then we'd like to think (happy to provide papers if needed be).

In general, HVAC models start with first law of thermodynamics to produce a heat transfer model. The latter will typically involve:

- Specific heat (amount of heat needed to raise temperature of 1kg by 1C)
- Heat transfer rate
- Heat flux
- Heat capacity
- Energy change
- Mass flow rate
- ... and more!

In general, there's a whole bunch of equations from physics that together can form a very good and robust engineering model.

Now, of course a neural network can in theory figure out any function with just one hidden layer. In practice, you'll find that you are asking way too much from your ANN - to figure out a mechanics of a heat transfer! Of course, it will be able to catch some of this stuff, but it will never be able to generalise as well as an equation. Inevitably you will get some weird results.